# parsing string for value having newline character

Tags: c#

In C#, what is the best way to parse the following string to capture the actual value "`Yes`" ?

> **InnerText = "\nPer Diem Allowed\n Per Diem Allowed\n Yes\n**

In other words, I want to detect the very last \n and capture the word what is before that.

Comment: You want to retrieve `Yes` from this string?

Comment: I would think that `Regex` is the way to go; more specifically, `Regex.Match()`.

Comment: Will the string contain more than one `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: No string will contain one Yes.. and I want to capture the value of Yes or No at the very end of \n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] parts = InnerText.Split("\n".ToCharArray());
string partIWant = parts[parts.Length - 2];
```

Comment: My bad! I got confused with the string literal, I was thinking that the C# string literal escape characters would be inside the string but this is actually referring to a line break in the string.

Comment: No worries. No harm, no foul.